# Trim off parenthesized text from columns that have it?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an `NVARCHAR(80)` column. Some column values end with a space, followed by a number within parentheses. (As shown below.)

Is there a SQL-Server syntax to remove the space, parentheses, and number from values that have them, but leave all other values unchanged?

For example, `"SANDFRAC4070 (1441316)"` would become `"SANDFRAC4070"`, and `"SAND FRACING 30 50 MESH"` would be unchanged.

**Sample Data**

```
SAND FRACING 100 MESH (1441317)
SAND FRACING 100 MESH (1441317)
SANDFRAC4070 (1441316)
SANDFRAC4070 (1441316)
SANDFRAC4070 (1441316)
SANDFRAC4070 (1441316)
SANDFRAC4070 (1441316)
SANDFRAC4070 (1441316)
SANDFRAC4070 (1441316)
SANDFRAC4070 (1441316)
SANDFRAC4070 (1441316)
SANDFRAC4070 (1441316)
SANDFRAC4070 (1441316)
SANDFRAC4070 (1441316)
SANDFRAC4070 (1441316)
SANDFRAC3050MES
SANDFRAC3050MES
SANDFRAC3050MES
SANDFRAC3050MES
SANDFRAC4070MES
SANDFRAC4070MES
SANDFRAC4070MES
SANDFRAC4070MES
SANDFRAC4070MES
SANDFRAC4070MES
SANDFRAC4070MES
SAND FRACING 30 50 MESH
SAND FRACING 30 50 MESH
```

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/WNbTN0vq) shows how to handle both the easy and some edge cases. Yes, your question is focused. Your attempt at solving the problem is less obvious.

Comment: @HABO: You solution for `SANDFRAC4070 (1441)(316)` is not correct because the rule "column values end with a space, followed by a number within parentheses." is not OK, there is no space

Comment: @Luuk Readily fixed with a one character change: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/SEkaie5z). I also added some additional test cases showing that it fails with "a number", e.g. _e_. I did not replicate each row, as did the OP, to determine if the results were repeatable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is `charindex()` with a "Fail-Safe"

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([SomeCol] varchar(50))  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('SANDFRAC4070 (1441316)')
,('SANDFRAC3050MES')
 
Select * 
      ,left(SomeCol,charindex(' (',SomeCol+' (')-1)
 From @YourTable
```

**Results**

```
SomeCol                  (No column name)
SANDFRAC4070 (1441316)   SANDFRAC4070
SANDFRAC3050MES          SANDFRAC3050MES
```

Comment: Thanks, this appears to work. Doing additional testing and checking out how it works.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case the comment in which I posted this [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/SEkaie5z) disappears I'll move it to an answer:

```
declare @Samples as Table ( Sample VarChar(80) );
insert into @Samples ( Sample ) values
  ( 'SAND FRACING 100 MESH (1441317)' ),
  ( 'SANDFRAC4070 (1441316)' ),
  ( 'SANDFRAC4070(1441316)' ),
  ( 'SANDFRAC3050MES' ),
  ( 'SAND FRACING 30 50 MESH' ),
  ( 'SAND FRACING (30) 50 MESH' ),
  ( 'SAND FRACING (30) (50) MESH' ),
  ( 'SANDFRAC4070 (1441)(316)' ),
  ( 'SANDFRAC4070 (1441) (316)' ),
  ( 'SANDWICH CHICKEN (NO ONION)' ),
  ( 'SAND ()' ),
  ( 'SAND (0)' ),
  ( 'SAND (-0)' ),
  ( 'SAND (6.022E+23)' ),
  ( 'SAND (e)' ),
  ( '' ),
  ( NULL );

with
  Step1 as (
    select Sample,
      -- Find the last open parenthesis by searching backwards from the end of the string.
      Len( Sample ) - CharIndex( '( ', Reverse( Sample ) ) as LastOpenParen
      from @Samples ),
  Step2 as (
    select Sample, LastOpenParen,
      case
        -- If there was no open parenthesis, or no string, then we're done.
        when LastOpenParen = Len( Sample ) or LastOpenParen is NULL then NULL
        -- The target substring runs from the last open parenthesis to the end of the string.
        else Substring( Sample, LastOpenParen + 1, 80 ) end as Target
      from Step1 )
  select Sample, Len( Sample ) as Length, LastOpenParen,
    case
      -- Nothing interesting.
      when Target is NULL then Sample
      -- A string in parentheses, but including a non-digit character.
      when Target like '(%[^0-9]%)' then Sample
      -- A string in parentheses with at least one digit and no non-digits.
      when Target like '(%[0-9]%)' then RTrim( Left( Sample, LastOpenParen ) )
      -- Empty parenteses.
      else Sample end as CorrectedSample
    from Step2;
```

Note that not every value that might be considered a *number* is handled as the OP was rather vague about decimal, negative, scientific, ... values.

Comment: I wasn't specific about them because they didn't matter. Any content at the end of the text that starts with *" ("* should be trimmed off.

Comment: @JonathanWood So why include noise like "a number within parentheses" in your question?